# How can I include an image that is tied to a user's database information?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, mysqli

I've been coding PHP for 2 weeks (it's not pretty) and I have not been able to find the answer to my question. I want an admin type user to be able to fill a form and post it to a page where base level users can view the content. I've gotten all of this to work like a charm, but my dilemma is to allow the admin user to include an image as well. Maybe I just don't know what to search for.

Here is the php code and the form for the admin user page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

include_once("connection.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) {
$adminid = $_SESSION['adminid'];
$adminemail = $_SESSION['adminemail'];

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $deadline = $_POST['deadline'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


        $sql_blog = "INSERT INTO blog (title, deadline, content, logoname)     VALUES    ('$title', '$deadline', '$content', '$logoname')";

        $query_blog =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql_blog);
        echo "<script>alert('Your inquiry has been posted')</script>";
    }

} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT adminid, adminemail, adminpassword, adminname FROM admin WHERE     adminemail = '$adminemail' LIMIT 1";

$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

if ($query) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $adminname = $row[3];
}

?>
```

and here is the code for the base level user page: (i commented out the image block where I want the admin's image to be shown.

```
 <main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row topbuffpost">
        <h1>business inquiries</h1>
        <hr>
        <?php  
        include_once('connection.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $content = $row['content'];
            $date = strtotime($row['deadline']);

        ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="card hoverable">

              <!--  <div class="card-image">
                  <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1">

                    <img src="">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="mask waves-effect">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                  </div>
                 </div> -->

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h5> <?php echo $title; ?> <br/> <h6>Deadline |<small> <?php echo date("j M, Y", $date); ?> </small> </h6></h5> <br/>

                        <p> <?php echo $content; ?> </p>
                        <div class="card-btn text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info blue-grey darken-2 btn-md waves-effect waves-light">Read more</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbsp propose a plan</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?> 

    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

All of this works perfectly, I just can't figure out how to have an image display in the same way as the title, deadline, and content. Youtube wont help either, too much outdated php + I haven't been coding long enough to really work things out on my own.

Comment: also, the "$logoname" tags are the variables I want to call the image.

Comment: Where are the images located? You can save the image name into database for each user and provide that info in image source. <img src="<?php echo $row['imageLink']; ?>">

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have a file called /logo that I tried saving it to. But the image names that uploaded to my database were not echoing with the rest of the text-based information. I've been playing around with $_FILES but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Comment: Do you see your file name in the database? How do you save them? Your current code doesn't show anything about how you save the logoname. It is empty.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all user images under a folder (let's call `/images/user`) and record the file name into database.

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $deadline = $_POST['deadline'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $logoname = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["logoname"]; // <-- Make sure your form is ready to submit an file
   // Update below as per your need.
   $target = 'images/users/' . $logoname;
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target);

   $sql_blog = "INSERT INTO blog (title, deadline, content, logoname)     VALUES    ('$title', '$deadline', '$content', '$logoname')";

   $query_blog =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql_blog);
   echo "<script>alert('Your inquiry has been posted')</script>";
 }
```

You can then display the image your page

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row topbuffpost">
        <h1>business inquiries</h1>
        <hr>
        <?php  
        include_once('connection.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $content = $row['content'];
            $date = strtotime($row['deadline']);
            $logoname = 'images/user/' . $row['logoname'];

        ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="card hoverable">

                <div class="card-image">
                  <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1">

                    <img src="<?php echo $logoname; ?>">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="mask waves-effect">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h5> <?php echo $title; ?> <br/> <h6>Deadline |<small> <?php echo date("j M, Y", $date); ?> </small> </h6></h5> <br/>

                        <p> <?php echo $content; ?> </p>
                        <div class="card-btn text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info blue-grey darken-2 btn-md waves-effect waves-light">Read more</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbsp propose a plan</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?> 

    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now:  Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test2/post.php on line 18

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpSJFkTs' to 'img/user/' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test2/post.php on line 18

Comment: I have edited 2 lines to fix that issue however there could be other things that you need to check in your form. Give it a try though.